# Parse multipart/form-data in scala

Tags: scala

I need to parse multipart/form-data content which is coming from the post method. I tried to read the content but it is displaying like this. this form-data contains the picture 
in the client side  [formData.append('photo', { uri: localUri, name: filename, type });]

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryY6jhcT6r7c7ynBJt
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="photo"

[object Object]
------WebKitFormBoundaryY6jhcT6r7c7ynBJt--
```

Comment: do you mean in play framework?

Comment: we are not using play framework. we are using Scalatra